# How to Automatically Click a button On a form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, event-handling

I have a working form application that has a button on it. I have the source code too. So now I am trying to run the application from schedule tasks on windows and I would like to change the code the to the click button action when the application runs. The problem is the form should be loaded first and then the click action should be fired. Do I need a timer to this? if so could you please give me a help with this? So it takes about 3-4 seconds to load the form application. so it should fire the click action after 5 seconds

Comment: Use the `Shown` event? (not sure if this is what you mean because your question is unclear)

Comment: Use [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) or [`Form.Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event, when that fires, call the same function that your button calls. No need to simulate the click

Comment: But what do you do in that button click. It is a totally automatic operation (meaning no input is required from the form)? If this is the case then try to refactor your code extracting the code from the button click and call that code from the command arguments passed to your main

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event will fire when the form is shown to the user for the first time, you can enter your event into this

```
 protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
 {
    base.OnShown(e);
    this.BtnClick(null, null);
 }
```

Comment: The Perform Click responses below are better answers IMO. Passing in nulls could be problematic if somebody overrides the event and wants to use sender or EventArgs.

Answer (score 3):

You can call button `click` event using [Button.PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) on [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event to ensure form is loaded.

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Button1.PerformClick(); 
}
```

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed;
>   subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or
>   invalidating and repainting will not raise this event, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

`buttonName.PerformClick();` 
**Call the button using PerformClick method**

Comment: improve your answer by adding more details if solution is also possible using  `PerformClick `  to make your answer more useful and understandable.Thanks

Answer (score -2):

you call call button click like this

Button_Click(sender,e)