# Auto click button in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button code that enable the connection to the network whenever the user click it.

```
private void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            EnableCommands(true);
            //Creating instance of Socket
            m_socClient = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream ,ProtocolType.Tcp );

            // retrieve the remote machines IP address
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse (txtIPAddr.Text);
            //A printer has open port 9100 which can be used to connect to printer
            int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16 ( txtPort.Text);
            //create the end point 
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint (ip.Address,iPortNo);
            //connect to the remote host
            m_socClient.Connect ( ipEnd );
            EnableCommands(false);
            //wait for data to arrive 
            WaitForData();
        }
        catch(SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (se.Message );
            EnableCommands(true);
        }

        page_counter();
    }
```

However now I want this code to auto run first without anyone click on it. I want to do this because I want the task scheduler to run this code everyday to do update. This program will run behind, and theres no interaction with users. Therefore I want this program to auto connect by itself. Is this possible? Please advise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878730/how-to-automatically-click-a-button-on-a-form-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this code in a method instead of button click and call that method from button click event and also from the Form's constructor after InitializeComponent().

```
public partial class Sample : Form
    {
        public Sample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CmdConnect(txtIPAddr.Text, txtPort.Text);
        }

        private void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            CmdConnect(txtIPAddr.Text, txtPort.Text);
        }

        private void CmdConnect(string txtIPAddr, string txtPort)
        {
            try
            {
                EnableCommands(true);
                //Creating instance of Socket
                m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // retrieve the remote machines IP address
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(txtIPAddr);
                //A printer has open port 9100 which can be used to connect to printer
                int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(txtPort);
                //create the end point 
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip.Address, iPortNo);
                //connect to the remote host
                m_socClient.Connect(ipEnd);
                EnableCommands(false);
                //wait for data to arrive 
                WaitForData();
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
                EnableCommands(true);
            }
            page_counter();
        }

// Other Methods
}
```

Comment: but still a button need to be click rite? I dont want any button to be click.because this program operate behind, no interaction with user.

Comment: If your form is loading then button need not be clicked. Whenever, the form object will be created, your above code will run. Just try to test this.

Comment: Hes saying create a method that contains the network code code and call the method from both the constructor and button handler. 

Though I thought the question was about how to execute/auto click the method the button calls automatically.

Comment: Ok. but sorry im new to this c# winform. Can you please guide me a little bit more? really appreciate it.

Comment: See, whenever windows form is shown on the screen, its constructor is called and there is a method inside that known as as InitializeComponent(). This method initializes all textboxes and other stuff in your form. After this method call, you can add method as suggested by Alex in his answer.

Comment: So do I have to create something like this?correct me if im wrong. public Form1()
  { InitializeComponent();
cmdConnect_Click(null, null);
  }

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample for you. You can refactor it more by passing the textbox values through method parameters instead of directly using them in the method. Also, IPAdress.Adress property is depricated, so consider using something else.

Answer (score 2):

Call `cmdConnect_Click(null, null)` in your constructor or where ever you want it to run first.

Answer (score 2):

You can raise click event of button control by calling `PerformClick()` on FormLoad() event. So it will auto run first without anyone clicking on it or when `Task Scheduler` runs your the application to do the update.

```
cmdConnect.PerformClick();
```

But I don't think sending click events is the best way.

If you just want to run the code which is in the try block from another place in the form, put the code into a separate method like `DoWork()` and call the method from anywhere you need to use it. That way you always have access to that function.

#### Example:

```
private void NetworkConnection()
{
    try
    {
        EnableCommands(true);
        //Creating instance of Socket
        m_socClient = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream ,ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // retrieve the remote machines IP address
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse (txtIPAddr.Text);
        //A printer has open port 9100 which can be used to connect to printer
        int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16 ( txtPort.Text);
        //create the end point 
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint (ip.Address,iPortNo);
        //connect to the remote host
        m_socClient.Connect ( ipEnd );
        EnableCommands(false);
        //wait for data to arrive 
        WaitForData();
    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {
        MessageBox.Show (se.Message );
        EnableCommands(true);
    }

    page_counter();
}
```

In Button Click event, just call `NetworkConnection()` method:

```
private void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkConnection();
}
```